# C# - generate xml requests from wsdl

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

I am trying  to  consume wsdl web services with  http requests . 
Example :

[Calculator web service](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx)

> ```
> <wsdl:types>
> <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
> <s:element name="Add">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int"/>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> <s:element name="AddResponse">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AddResult" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> <s:element name="Subtract">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int"/>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> <s:element name="SubtractResponse">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SubtractResult" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> <s:element name="Multiply">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int"/>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> <s:element name="MultiplyResponse">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MultiplyResult" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> <s:element name="Divide">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int"/>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> <s:element name="DivideResponse">
> <s:complexType>
> <s:sequence>
> <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DivideResult" type="s:int"/>
> </s:sequence>
> </s:complexType>
> </s:element>
> </s:schema>
> </wsdl:types>
> ```
>
> That  is  part of  Wsdl file which contains  names and  parameter definitions  of methods  . 
>   Request body  of  Method **Add** should be like that  :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Add>
         <tem:intA>?</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>?</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Question:**

How to get  web service methods  , their names , and  request body programmatically ?

Comment: Do you have sample of Xml (not just the schema)?

Comment: @jdweng sample  is  showed  above  .  That  is the sample of **Add Method**  and was crated by Soap UI  .

Comment: The wsdl web services posted is only a schema file and doesn't contain any data.  I can't tell if the wsdl web services also contains data after the schema info.

Comment: The wsdl data  is not contain any data  . but  data is crated  on base  of  that  . As  You see    
<tem:Add>
         <tem:intA>?</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>?</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
is created  on base  of : 
<s:element name="Add">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
@jdweng

Comment: I know.  I was just asking for a sample to do my testing.

Comment: @jdweng  . i understand .  I am trying  to do same  process what  SOAP UI does  .